# AS3 Passing and getting data to ASP

Tags: asp.net, actionscript-3

I've been researching for days on the issude but till now I still haven found a solution yet.
I have 0 knowledge on ASP. And I just want to able to pass and get var/text from ASP.

Anyone kind enuff to guide me how I can furthur from here?

```
private function loadASP():void {
        var aspSend:URLRequest=new URLRequest("testASP.asp");
        var aspLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

        aspLoader.load(aspSend);

        trace("did send");
        //aspLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processASP);
    }

    private function processASP(e:Event):void {
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why have you commented the call to `addEventListener` method? Uncomment it (and move it up two lines so that it comes before the `load` call). If the url is correct, the `processASP` method will be called when the response arrives (in a real life application, make sure you listen for ioError and securityError on the [URLLoader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/net/URLLoader.html#includeExamplesSummary) - check the link for examples on doing this). You can read the response as `e.target.data` in the `processASP` method.

```
private function processASP(e:Event):void 
{
  var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target);
  trace("Response is " + loader.data);
}
```

---

`URLLoader` can also be used to send data to the asp page (server).

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
data.something = "someData";
data.somethingElse = "moreData";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url.asp");
request.data = data;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;//or GET
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
//listen for other events
ldr.load(request);
```

Comment: This answer (and a couple of similar posts of mine regarding `URLLoader`) was wrong (I corrected them). It has been in SO for three weeks and surprisingly no one down-voted or even noticed it.