# Flex and CGI Newbie: How do I get them to talk

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, cgi

I am a Flex developer and never used CGI before. I wanted to create a solution whereby A flex would call a CGI script to read a database. Ive been trying to look for examples on how such a solution would work. I was hoping someone on here might be able to shed some light as to how this would work, and what are the various components required.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the `URLLoader` class. Load the CGI url using the urlloader class - execute queries using cgi script and return the response - handle the results in the `complete` event handler of `URLLoader`. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624136/as3-passing-and-getting-data-to-asp/1624251#1624251) for details on using the URLLoader class.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest way is to output XML from your CGI and use Flex's HTTPService to connect to the CGI and get data.  Sending updates can be done through sending HTTP Request Parameters via HTTPService.