# How to call a CGI script in FLEX 3 and display the result back in flex application?

Tags: apache-flex, cgi, call

How can i call a CGI script in flex 3? 
Also how can i retrieve the result of exection of that cgi script?

For example,
lets say my CGI script(hello.cgi) just display "hello world".
How can i call this script from flex 3 and then retrieve the result, 
i.e. hello world , so that it can be displayed on my flex application.

I am new to flex and would highly appreciate any help/hint.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flex and CGI Newbie: How do I get them to talk](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1641561/flex-and-cgi-newbie-how-do-i-get-them-to-talk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[URLLoader](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLLoader.html) is what you need.

```
private var u:URLLoader;
private function initialize():void {
    u=new URLLoader();
    var ur:URLRequest=new URLRequest("http://mysite.com/script.cgi");
    u.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, dataReceived);
    u.load(ur);
}

private function dataReceived(e:Event):void {
    Alert.show(u.data.toString());
}
```