# How do i send data from flash to html page?

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I would like to know that how we could send out data from a flash movie to html , php, aspx page so that  that data could use for further calculation.

Comment: Is the Flash an object in the page, or is it connecting to the "page" as a service?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `URLLoader` class for communications between the flash movie and whatever you have at the server. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624136/as3-passing-and-getting-data-to-asp/1624251#1624251) for sample code and links.

Answer (score 0):

You would normally do a POST or GET from the flash movie (using the URL of a PHP or whatever page you have on your server).  The server page would then process the parameters in the POST or GET.

Example: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=145421

Answer (score 0):

Flash has a bridge to the page that contains it that will allow you to interact with that page via JavaScript. It is called [ExternalInterface](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html).

I missed the 2.0 tag there. Don't know if this is still applicable with AS2