# AS3 and mySQL or XML: Saving user votes on server from a flash movie

Tags: php, mysql, flash, actionscript-3, communication

A project of mine involves a flash movie (.swf) in a webpage, where the user has to pick from a number of items, and has the option to **thumbs up** or **thumbs down** (vote on) each item.

So far I have gotten this to work during each run of the application, as it is currently loading the data from an XML file - and the data is still static at the moment.

I need to persist these votes on the server using a database (mySQL), such that when the page is reloaded, the votes aren't forgotten.

Has anyone done this sort of thing before?

The two mains methods that I have found on the 'net are

1. either direct communication between AS3 and the SQL using some sort of framework, or
2. passing the SQL query to a PHP file, which then executes the SQL query and returns the SQL to AS3.

Which of these methods is the better option?

For the latter method (involving PHP), I have been able to find resources on how to acheive this when attempting to **retrieve** information from the database (i.e. a read operation), but not when attempting to **send** information to the database (i.e. a write operation, which is needed when the users vote). How is this done?

Thank you!

---

#### Edit: Implemented solution

Somewhere in the PHP file:

```
if ($action == "vote")
{
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $upvotes = $_POST['upvotes'];
    $query = "UPDATE `thetable` SET `upvotes` = '$upvotes' WHERE `thetable`.`id` = '$id' LIMIT 1 ;";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Somewhere in the ActionsScript:

```
    public function writeToDb(action:String)
    {
        var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var postVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
        var postReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest();

        postVars.action = action;
        postVars.id = id;
        postVars.upvotes = upvotes;

        postReq.url = <NAME_OF_PHP_FILE>;
        postReq.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        postReq.data = postVars;

        loader.load(postReq);
        loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onWriteToDbComplete);
    }
```

Comment: It is essentially **never** a good idea to access a database directly from a swf. You can make arbitrary TCP socket connections, so it is technically possible, but SWFs are easy to decompile and 100% completely insecure.

Comment: @Joel, yeah I agree, after doing some reading of my own, I figured that it would involve storing the DB's password in the swf, which is an obvious security loophole if it can be decompiled easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of any framework that supports method-1.

I would use method-2 - but instead of making the query within Flash and passing it to PHP, I would rather pass the related data and construct the query in PHP itself. This is safer because it is less susceptible to SQL injection attacks.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624136/as3-passing-and-getting-data-to-asp/1624251#1624251) has an example of sending data from flash to the server - it talks about ASP, but the method is same for PHP (or any technology) - just change the URL.

Within the php code, you can read the sent data from the post `$_POST` (or `$_GET`) variable.

```
$something = $_POST["something"]
```

Comment: @Amargosh Thank you! +1 for constructing query in PHP, and +1 for your other answer as well, cos it worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Many different options:

[AMFPHP](http://www.amfphp.org/) - binary messaging format between PHP and Actionscript/Flash.

[LoadVars](http://flash-creations.com/notes/servercomm_loadvars.php) - for POSTing and GETing values to a PHP script.

[JSON](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/) - Using the AS3Corelib you can post JSON formatted data to your web site (just like an AJAX script does).