# Generate Flash objects server-side with .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, actionscript-3, flex4

How can I create an array of Flash objects (for instance, Buttons) on the server-side using .NET, then stream them as binaries?

In essence, I would like to decrease the time spent on the client creating objects out of base primitives.

Comment: What do you mean in "all routines" and in "base primitives"? There is AS3 serialization format AMF, maybe you can go with it, but first answer to my question this will make me understand why you are going in this direction. Maybe there is better solution.

Comment: by : ( the basic idea is to decrease the time on the client for moving trough all routines for creating the object from base primitives ) - I mean that there is a complex calculations for a creating of one object, and I wish to make them on the server, and stream to the client just the result object, which to be directly used inside the flash application.

Comment: This can be accomplished with Flash Remoting. In the past I've used FluorineFX (http://www.fluorinefx.com/), but it hasn't been updated in a long time.

Comment: So - with FluorineFX i can create serverside via C# some instance of a Flash class ( or binary representation of such ) and stream it to the Flash application ?

Comment: Just an idea. Maybe run one flash application on server for these calculations? I'm guessing you have enough resource on server.

Comment: Yordan: yes, that's exactly what Flash Remoting is used for. And yes, the data is serialized in a binary format – see the description for the AMF3 format here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ObjectEncoding.html.

Comment: seems like fluorinefx it is.. @T Graham please set your comment as an answer, so i can accept it.

Comment: Thanks Yordan, that's nice of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished with Flash Remoting. In the past I've used FluorineFX ([fluorinefx.com](http://www.fluorinefx.com/)), but it hasn't been updated in a long time.

You might also want to look into WebORB for .NET (http://www.themidnightcoders.com/products/weborb-for-net/overview.html), which is another solution for Flash Remoting. Unlike FluorineFX, WebORB is still being supported. However, the full version of WebORB isn't free and it looks like they won't tell you how much it costs unless you talk to one of their salespeople.

Comment: You can ask WebORB sales persons for the community license. I am not sure if they still have that option, but it used to work a year ago.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: [AS3 Passing and getting data to ASP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1624136/as3-passing-and-getting-data-to-asp?rq=1)

It tells you can pass data to an ASP.NET server through URLLoader. 'You can read the response as e.target.data in the processASP method.'

Also from the page:
URLLoader can also be used to send data to the asp page (server).

```
var ldr:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
var data:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
data.something = "someData";
data.somethingElse = "moreData";
var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("url.asp");
request.data = data;
request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;//or GET
ldr.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
//listen for other events
ldr.load(request);
```

The server would have to be a live streaming page, though.

Comment: this is only the not so important part. The most important part is how to create a flash object server side ?

Answer (score 0):

The `Flex Compiler` can create SWF code from `.as` files, but you need to have it installed on your server. SWF can then be compressed as binary, so it should fit your needs.

The next step is to pass the URL to the generated SWF to your application in an `<embed>` code or through an `ExternalInterface`. However...

I would suggest not trying to reinvent the wheel. If you want a smaller size and cache support for SWFs, the easier way is to send a binary configuration file (using `<embed>`/`ExternalInterface`) which is gzipped JSON or XML to the SWF application with functionality to generate the UI you want based on its data. You can use Flash, Flex or OpenSource components (such as MinimalComps) - or even write your own components to have exactly what you want in the size you want.

Comment: Probably i haven't described the issue correctly.
- I dont wana create the flash application on the server, but just a separate object, which to be streamed to the application.
So .. - no SFW - just an object - instance from a specific class - like instance of Line or instance of Vector.<Int>, filled with Integer values.